# Django-neomodels driver error while running python manage.py install_labels

Tags: python, django, neo4j

I am running the **paradise papers** neo4j project tutorial, I have created all my models but I get the error below while generating database indexes.That is when I run command: `python manage.py install_labels`

My requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
certifi==2021.10.8
Django==3.2.8
django-neomodel==0.0.7
djangorestframework==3.11.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
neo4j-driver==4.3.1
neomodel==4.0.4
pytz==2021.1
Shapely==1.7.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
white-noise==3.3.1
```

and added the following in the settings.py:

`NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL = os.environ.get('NEO4J_BOLT_URL','bolt://neo4j:1234@127.0.0.1:7687').`

Error:

````
  File "/Users/harmankibue/Desktop/Data/Projects/Django-Projects/papers_search/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/harmankibue/Desktop/Data/Projects/Django-Projects/papers_search/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_neomodel/management/commands/install_labels.py", line 12, in handle
    install_all_labels(stdout=self.stdout)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 153, in install_all_labels
    install_labels(cls, quiet=False, stdout=stdout)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neomodel/core.py", line 110, in install_labels
    db.cypher_query("CREATE INDEX on :{0}({1}); ".format(
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 35, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 230, in cypher_query
    response = session.run(query, params)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/work/simple.py", line 221, in run
    self._connect(self._config.default_access_mode, database=self._config.database)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/work/simple.py", line 118, in _connect
    self._connection = self._pool.acquire(
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py", line 805, in acquire
    return self._acquire(self.address, timeout)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py", line 660, in _acquire
    connection = self.opener(address, timeout)
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py", line 787, in opener
    return Bolt.open(
  File "/Users/harmankibue/opt/anaconda3/envs/papers_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neo4j/io/__init__.py", line 337, in open
    raise BoltHandshakeError("The Neo4J server does not support communication with this driver. This driver have support for Bolt Protocols {}".format(supported_versions), address=address, request_data=handshake, response_data=data)
neo4j._exceptions.BoltHandshakeError: The Neo4J server does not support communication with this driver. This driver have support for Bolt Protocols dict_keys([Version(3, 0), Version(4, 0), Version(4, 1), Version(4, 2), Version(4, 3)])```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection problem related to Bolt Protocol and Neo4j using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625674/connection-problem-related-to-bolt-protocol-and-neo4j-using-python)